# How to use fetched data with Next.js and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, fetch-api

I am new to Next.js and TypeScript. I am trying `map()` over the data from JsonPlaceholder

My `getStaticProps`:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    const data = await res.json()
    return {
        props: { auth0Data: data },
    }
}
```

My NextPage:

```
interface Auth0DataProps {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    username: string,
}

type Props = {
    auth0Data: Auth0DataProps
}

const Dashboard: NextPage<{ auth0Data: Props }> = ({ auth0Data }) => {
    console.log(auth0Data) // logs the data as an object
    return (
        <LayoutComponent title="User profile">
          {auth0Data.map(data=> ( // I GET AN ERROR
            ...
           )
        )
 }
```

The error I'm getting:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Props'

Comment: What error do you get? [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an array method, if `auth0Data` is an object it won't work on it.

Comment: The data shows in the browser but the typescript says different: `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Props'` and data I am getting back is ie data - `Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: Ah, so it's a TypeScript error that you're getting. That's because you're typing `auth0Data` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you're passing through the `auth0Data` prop is an array, then you're typing the `Dashboard` component incorrectly - `auth0Data` should be an array of `Auth0DataProps`, and `NextPage` should receive `Props` type as the generic.

```js
type Props = {
    auth0Data: Auth0DataProps[]
}

const Dashboard: NextPage<Props> = ({ auth0Data }) => {
    // Remaining code
}
```

Comment: The data should be coming in as an array-like object, that's why I am able to iterate over the data and it shows in the browser so my implementation is the problem :  

`auth0Data.map(data => <p key={data.id}>{data.name}</p>`

Comment: Did you also change the `Dashboard` component type to `NextPage<Props>`? Looks like you missed that from your snippet.

Comment: yes I changed props but still getting the same [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ucRsxFK.png)

Answer (score 0):

The most common error is the wrong interpretation of your fetched data. And as far as I can see, you get an object from your server, which means you can't use the `array.map()` function ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

Typescript can't really help you there as it interprets your code not during runtime but on compile time. As a result, you have to make sure that the received data matches the specified types.